# Pass data in React FullCalendar with API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm getting some data with an API call and Data looks like this

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 7, 
            "comments": "", 
            "origin": "Terrassa, Spain", 
            "destination": "Delft, Netherlands",
            "total_trucks": 0,
            "material_type": "0", 
            "scheduled_date": "2019-09-29T01:01:00", 
            "offered_price": 0, 
            "weight": 7979879, 
            "status": "Assigned",
            "posted_on": "2019-09-23T15:24:39.946644",
            "All_India": true,
            "Andhra_Pradesh": false,
            "Assam": false,
            "Bihar": false,
            ...
            "West_Bengal": false,
            "owner": 1,
            "truck_type": 2,
            "truck_name": 139
        }
{
            "id": 9, 
            "comments": "", 
            "origin": "Teyty, Spain", 
            "destination": "Derry, Netherlands",
            "total_trucks": 0,
            "material_type": "0", 
            "scheduled_date": "2019-09-29T01:01:00", 
            "offered_price": 0, 
            "weight": 7979879, 
            "status": "Assigned",
            "posted_on": "2019-09-23T15:24:39.946644",
            "All_India": true,
            "Andhra_Pradesh": false,
            "Assam": false,
            "Bihar": false,
            ...
            "West_Bengal": false,
            "owner": 1,
            "truck_type": 2,
            "truck_name": 139
        }
    ]

}
```

From this data I want schedule_date in 'date' field in my events of reactFullCalender and total_weight and total_trucks in title of those event.
What I've tried so far gives me output as `Object object` in events on calendar screen. 
My code for that is:

```
<FullCalendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]}
events={[{ title: this.state.calendarEvents, date: '2019-09-22'] />
```

And my API call looks like this:

```
 const calendarEvent = await getEventsData();
        this.setState({calendarEvents:calendarEvent});

        console.log(calendarEvent,
            "calendarEvents");
```

And my states looks like this:

```
this.state = {
            calendarEvents:[
                {totalTrucks:''},
                {totalWeight:''}]};}
```

All I want is that API call calendarEvent gets the data and I want to feed that in events in fullCalender

Comment: you want to display date only in calendar?. is it array of object?

Comment: I want to display schedule_date and total_weight and total_trucks which is their in the data I've shown above. Needless to say, If I can access any one field then I can show rest of it also. and yes it is an array of objects. As ``` Events[
{"material_type": "0", "scheduled_date": "2019-09-29T01:01:00", "offered_price": 0, "weight": 7979879, "status":
"Assigned", "posted_on": "2019-09-23T15:24:39.946644", "All_India": true, "Andhra_Pradesh": false, "Assam": false,}
]}

Comment: in events you are passing calendarEvents which you got from api but did you customize events file to iterate your array of objects?

Comment: Its the same file. I'm getting data from from API and in that I have to take that data and pass into events of fullCalendar. I'm quite new to this so any kind of help would be helpful for this.

Comment: use the [events-as-function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) pattern to retrieve the data from the API and then transform it before you send it to fullCalendar. This is better than supplying a static list for a number of reasons (mainly that it's dynamic, so it will request more events from the API server whenever the user changes the date in the calendar, and also you don't have to worry about the syntax so much in the calendar definition)

Comment: But if you _do_ want to do it using your current approach, then your attempt makes no sense. `this.state.calendarEvents` is a list of events. So how can you set that as the title of a single event? I'm not really sure what you thought you were doing there. You first need to create a new array of objects which are in the [correct format required by fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing) and then pass that into your `events` option. Which is why, really, it's better to have a dynamic function for doing this task.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this:

```
setStateAsync(state) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.setState(state, resolve)
    });
```

To set your state asynchronously after we get it from the data.

[This has a reference where we set State asynchronously.](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802)

Comment: I cannot use this example as it is sending a single text in API call whereas I'm passing an array of objects.

Comment: @chirag that's not a valid reason to avoid this example. The data you put into the state can be anything - an array, an object, a single value, whatever you like. The point of this example is the async design pattern, not the content of the data. Having said that, it's unclear what this answer actually resolves in terms of your specific issue. See my comments above, on the main thread, for a discussion of that.

Comment: I think what can be done here is passing separate props from the parent component to FullCalendar component. e.g. date as a separate prop and event params as another prop where we can pass totalTrucks and totalWeight

Comment: I got the answer by passing it like 
```events={[{ title: this.state.calendarEvent.events[0].weight.toString(), date:this.state.calendarEvent.events[0].scheduled_date.slice(0,10)  }]}```

Comment: But again a problem remains as I have to loop over this to get all the data or map data over no. of entries

Comment: @chirag that's why you need to use events-as-a-function. It would allow you a place to run such a loop. See my comments above on the main question.